# Separating layers in CodeIgniter for N-Tier architecture

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to PHP world. However I have worked on .NET web area fairly. While designing the application architecture, broadly categorize into UI, Business, Data Access layers. And MVC falls as part of UI layer. The models are the objects that hold the data to help building UI and transfer the data across layers.

When it comes to PHP CodeIgniter, all the examples I came across are over-simplifying the layering approach. The Controller holds the business and Models perform the data operations.

I am just wondering how to separate the business and data access layers with CI.

Comment: You kinda don't. Most of the popular PHP frameworks just use various active record style ORMs. Maybe with an exception of Symfony 2.x and Zend 2.x

Comment: add all the query(DAO operations - CRUD methods) in Model classes, don't write any crud methods in Contollers or View templates, map URL in Controller methods and call Models methods in there to get the data and set to $data[] array and use them in Views

Comment: @buddhi did you even understand his question? Do you know what "business/domain layer" is?

Comment: usually when I've worked in java using Spring fw and Hibernate I've used 4 layers, View, Controller(call service methods), Service(has business service methods), DAO(has CRUD methods), but when I'm working with Codeigniter I'm only using 3 layers View, Controller, Model(has both DAO methods and Service methods) so in Codeigniter MVC fw, Model layer has both the DAO and Service responsibilities

Comment: Well .. in CodeIgniter the controllers also have responsibilities which normally would be handled by service layer. And the "views" are just glorified templates. My point is: CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC or n-Tier.

Comment: CodeIgniter's doc says it's based on MVC: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html